# Unable to validate multiselectbox in zend framework

Tags: php, arrays, zend-framework

i am using zendframe work for my site, I am using the below mentioned code for a multiselect dropdown box.

```
$newscat        = new Default_Models_Common();
$row_newscat    = $newscat->fillSelect_new("casestudiesservice","serviceId","serviceName", "serviceStatus='1' ORDER BY serviceName ASC");
$casestudiesServices = new Zend_Form_Element_Multiselect('casestudiesServices[]',array(
                            'class'     => 'text',
                            'value' => $view->row->casestudiesServices,
                            'required'   => true));
```

It working fine but i am unable to validate that box.It return empty array

> (Array (
>       [0] => Array
>           (
>           ) ))..

Comment: is it even showing up properly I don't see an addMultiOptions anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try following method. Maybe it will useful to you.

Use multi select element like below:

```
$multi = new Zend_Form_Element_Multiselect('users');
$multi->setMultiOptions(array(
    //'option value' => 'option label'
    '21' => 'Milap',
    '22' => 'jay',
    '23' => 'Sandip'
));
$form->addElement($multi);
```

You can get the values of element like this:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $form = new MyForm();

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {

        if ($form->isValid($request->getPost())) {

            $values = $form->getValues();
            $users = $values['users'];
            var_dump($users);
        }
    }
    $this->view->form = $form;
}
```

Here , $users will contain an array of the values that have been selected:

```
array(
    0 => '21',
    1 => '23'
)
```

Good luck.

Comment: again its comes like that...  i have one doubt the multiselect option displays like this <select class="text" helper="formSelect" multiple="multiple" id="casestudiesServices" name="casestudiesServices[]">
    <option label="Please Select Service" value="0">Please Select Service</option>
    <option label="Floor" value="5">Floor</option>
    <option label="PressRoof" value="3">PressRoof</option>
    <option label="Urban Advantage" value="4">Urban Advantage</option>
</select>  is it correct?